# Long time operation in Application.onCreate()?

Tags: android

My app has to fetch some settings from sever before any other component, e.g. Anctivity, Server, can start. So I put the long-time http operation in Application.onCreate(). Is Application.onCreate() the right place to put the long-time operation? Will it cause ANR (Application Not Responding)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Thread or ASyncTask for communicate with server.
Android don't support communicate(send, receive) with server in UI Thread.
onCreate is UI Thread. So it's impossible.

Comment: I know I can use thread or AsyncTask, but how can I make sure the http operation finishes before other component starts? For example, if the process of my app is killed by OS, and then a service in my app is restarted because it is sticky service. In the case, I want to make sure the http operation finishes before the service starts.

Comment: If it is an Activity, first show empty activity and http operation. http operation is finished, send message using handler. handler change activity what you want. It's such as same the loading page.

Comment: In service, one service is same thing activity. If you make two service, one service do http operation. Http operation finished, it's service start second service what you want. first service can stop when start second service.

Comment: Yes, that's doable. But the issue is that, I have 10 services in my app. Then I have to put this trick into every service, and make them 20 services. The code like this is hard to maintain.

Comment: Then, you just make one service for start your 20 service. just add value for selecting service in 20 services.

Comment: Another way is service is start nothing, just http operation. if http operation is finish, start your code.